# How to take output from JTextArea and pass to another method

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am building a simple frontend gui to the linux command line program "mpg123".  I have built a drag and drop window that records the file path of the folder that has been dropped into a JTextArea.  Like this..

```
new FileDrop(System.out, textArea, new FileDrop.Listener() { 
         public void filesDropped(File[] files) { 
                  for( int i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) { 
                            try { textArea.append( files[i].getCanonicalPath());
                            } catch( java.io.IOException e ) {}
                            } 
                  }   
         });
```

I would like to get the file path from `try{textArea.append(files[i].getCanonicalPath())` and place that into another method that deals with the ProcessBuilder class.

How can I get this file path out of this method and into another?

I am really new to Java, thanks for reading.

Comment: `How can I get this file path out of this method and into another?` Get the text from the `JTextArea.getText()`, or assign it to a field that your code can access. And...`catch( java.io.IOException e ) {}` I recommend against swallowing Exceptions - at the very least print out the stack trace.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) I would recommend a `JList` (or `JTable`) over a `JTextArea` for this, since the latter requires some extra logic to separate the text into multiple file paths, which will be tricky, especially given there is no apparent separator (e.g. tab or newline) separating them.

Comment: Thanks guys!  I appreciate the advice.

Comment: *"Thanks guys!"* I'd prefer to see an MCVE than receive 'thanks'. *"I appreciate the advice."* Don't just appreciate it, implement the suggestions and [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39645204/edit)! And a tip: Add @copeg (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.